# Looking for a NodeJS Discord Bot command list

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've recently learned some NodeJS because I wanted to try making a discord bot however I am struggling to find commands.

For example, I tried using *message.author* in an if statement and didn't realise my mistake of not using *message.author.tag* until a good while of searching.

I've looked at the Discord Documentation but I couldn't find that and other command s I was looking for, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could link me a list of Discord Bot NodeJS commands.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking. It helps to post the code that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean commands? From what I remember discord.js has a comprehensive documentation. 
For example: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author you see that message.author is of type user (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), which has access to the following methods (only some):

```
removeFriend
send
sendCode 
sendFile
sendMessage
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you! It seems I was looking at the wrong documentation (this one https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-user) which doesn't have all the I material needed.

Comment: That's the official discord api. If you want to make your own library (like discord.js) you will need to use that